# server side search functionality

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures

need to implement server side Search functionality

My requirement is as follows:

The string inserted in the textbox has to checked in every column-data in the database. if it matches or the string is contained by any of the column-data in the database that row is valid for displaying. 
There is a pagination part too, that is also handled in the DB and the stored procedure has to send only an specified no of rows calculated based on the ***pageIndex***, and ***rowCount*** passed to the stored Procedure, this calculation also is happening in the stored procedure only.

In the Stored procedure we are pulling the data from Different table using joins and pushing it to a temporary table, and finally the data from the temporary table is sent back.

Here my problem is I am not able to use the ***Contains()*** method for searching the pattern so what should be the approach to wards this functionality. so that this can be done efficiently??

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check following query. You need to replace test with the value you want to search. This will give Column name and value of matching string. I hope this will help you to find your answer.

```
Declare @SearchStr nvarchar(100)
set @SearchStr='test'

DECLARE @Results TABLE  (ColumnName nvarchar(370), ColumnValue nvarchar(3630))
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(256), @ColumnName nvarchar(128), @SearchStr2 nvarchar(110)
SET  @TableName = ''
SET @SearchStr2 = QUOTENAME('%' + @SearchStr + '%','''')

WHILE @TableName IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @ColumnName = ''
    SET @TableName = 
    (
        SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME))
        FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
        WHERE       TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
            AND QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) > @TableName
            AND OBJECTPROPERTY(
                    OBJECT_ID(
                        QUOTENAME(TABLE_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME)
                         ), 'IsMSShipped'
                           ) = 0
    )

    WHILE (@TableName IS NOT NULL) AND (@ColumnName IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @ColumnName =
        (
            SELECT MIN(QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME))
            FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE       TABLE_SCHEMA    = PARSENAME(@TableName, 2)
                AND TABLE_NAME  = PARSENAME(@TableName, 1)
                AND DATA_TYPE IN ('char', 'varchar', 'nchar', 'nvarchar')
                AND QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME) > @ColumnName
        )

        IF @ColumnName IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Results
            EXEC
            (
                'SELECT ''' + @TableName + '.' + @ColumnName + ''', LEFT(' + @ColumnName + ', 3630) 
                FROM ' + @TableName + ' (NOLOCK) ' +
                ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' LIKE ' + @SearchStr2
            )
        END
    END 
END

SELECT ColumnName, ColumnValue FROM @Results`
```